# How to start a program without interrupting my current session?

Tags: linux, terminal

I'am working on some code or document and I need an additional program like IntellJ e.g. How can I start this program in the background without popping up and interrupting me on my work? Often I start something to have it ready after I finished reading.

EDIT: I'am Working on Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `&` after the command to send it to background. If you don't want to see output, just add `>/dev/null 2>&1 &`